# append the count to each row in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code and when I want to add the count to the beginning of the texts const so it will display in the table row.

```
const getters = [item => item.count, item => formatDate(item.date), item => item.num, item => item.body];
var count = 0;
  for (let row of rows) {
    count = count + 1;
    const texts = getters.map(getter => getter(row));
    //alert(count + texts)
    const rowWithCount = count + texts;
    //alert(rowWithCount);
    resultsBody.appendChild(createRowWithTexts(rowWithCount));
  }
};
```

what I have does not work; it displays the count but messes up the other columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `const rowWithCount = count + texts;` you are adding number to array, in javascript it will resolve to a string, is that what you want? Or you looking to push count to your array, in this case you should do `texts.push(count);` and if you want for count to be first element in array you could do `texts = [count].concat(texts)`

Regarding number + array = string. Here is the example:

```
1 + [10,10] // resolves to "110,10"
```